# How to create a nested list in python by appending to an existing list

Tags: python, list, nested

I have a list called address_list and I want to iterate through it. Each value in the address_list I iterate through is run through another function which will return a new list called temp_list. I then want to nest the values of temp_list under the original value in address_list before moving on and doing the same thing to the next value in address_list.

Essentially it should look like this (with the address_list index on the left and the temp_list on the right):

[0] - [1,2,3]

[1] - [1,5,6,7,8,35]

[2] - [3,543,34,84,3,8,53]

This is the code I am trying to use:

```
for i in range(0,len(address_list)):
   
    #some code skipped where file_path_simple gets new values each time
    with open(file_path_simple, 'r') as fp:
        for ln in fp:
            ln = ln.strip('\n')
            temp_list.append(ln)
        fp.close()

    for j in temp_list:
        address_list[i].append(j)
```

This is giving me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "z:[path_redacted]\tracer.py", line 155, in <module> 
    address_list[i].append([]) 
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

The full code is LONG but hopefully this chunk will give a better idea:

```
address_list = []
temp_list = []
G = nx.Graph()
address_list.append(address)

#adds the root
G.add_node(address_list[0])

for i in range(0,len(address_list)):
    #print for testing purposes
    print(address_list[i])
    
    if i == target:
        tracePath(address, address_list[i])
    
    #query the address
    txQuery(address_list[i])
    parser()

    #write output to temp_list which will be the nested list
    file_path_simple = r'Z:\[path_redacted]\tx_list_simple.txt'
    with open(file_path_simple, 'r') as fp:
        for ln in fp:
            ln = ln.strip('\n')
            temp_list.append(ln)
        fp.close()

    #create the nested list for associated addresses
    address_list[i].append([])
    for j in temp_list:
        address_list[i].append(j)

    #create the children of the parent node which was queried
    for i in address_list[0][i]:
        G.add_node(i)
        G.add_edge(*[address_list[0],i])
        address_list.append(i)
    
    temp_list.clear()
```

Comment: Your `temp_list` is going to end up containing multiple copies of all the items by the end since you never clear it.  But why are you re-reading the same file over and over inside the loop anyway?

Comment: For the sake of not bloating the question with irrelevant code I've skipped a bunch of code where file_path_simple gets new values each time. I know that part of the code works so I didn't want to complicate the question.

Comment: What does `address_list` contain at the start?  That's the thing that's producing your bug so it's definitely not irrelevant.  :)

Comment: Please edit your question so that the problem is [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Right now we can only guess at the exact problem and solution.

Comment: address_list starts off containing a single value being at index 0 which is a result of earlier user input. I've tested that it definitely accepts this value. The contents of temp_list are first appened to index 0 (creating a nested list) then are all appended again but to address_list (so address list grows with each step). However the code never gets this far, it returns the AttributeError above when trying to create the nested list.

Comment: What "single value"?  A string?  You can't append to a string to create a list; that's not how either strings or lists work.  Are you sure you don't want to create a *dictionary* where the original strings are the keys and your lists are the values?

Comment: Please show the full traceback, including the line number

Comment: I'm trying to append to nest a second list at index 0 of address_list. I'm not trying to append to the string itself - this is where the error is coming from. How do I make it append a nested list at index 0?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "z:\[path_redacted]\tracer.py", line 155, in <module>
    address_list[i].append([])
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
I don't know how to add line numbers to the original question.

Comment: Hint: `print(type(address_list[i]))`. If that is not a list, and is instead `str`. then you are trying to append to a string.

Comment: So, `address_list.append(address)`? What is `address`? This is not in your question, thus why we asked to create a [mcve]

Comment: It is indeed a string which is the problem. Thinking about this some more I don't think it is possible to do what I want to do. I will have to think of another way of approaching the problem. Thanks, it's resolved my issue by making me realise it can't be done the way I want to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, you want to read a file into a list, then put that list into another one? You don't need to do that in a loop

But you can still loop over the `address_list` **after** it is populated from that file

```
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_node(address)

address_list = []

file_path_simple = r'Z:\[path_redacted]\tx_list_simple.txt'
with open(file_path_simple, 'r') as fp:
    temp_list = [ln.strip('\n') for ln in fp]
    address_list.append(temp_list)

for i, a in enumerate(address_list):
    if i == target:
        tracePath(address, a)
    
    # query the address
    txQuery(a)
    parser()
```

Comment: Yep, this answers the original question. I actually did away with the whole nested list for my application (I found a better solution) but this answers the original question.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you wan't to replace the element at the value i by temp_list?
If it's that here is some code (not tested):
code 1:

```
for i, _ in enumerate(address_list): 
    """enumerate take your list and transform it into a list contening a tuple contening the index and the value -> enumerate(["a", "b", "c"]) == [(0, "a"), (1, "b"), (2, "c")]"""
    temp_list = [] # I think you don't need to have the old value
    with open(file_path_simple, 'r') as fp:
        for ln in fp:
            ln = ln.strip('\n')
            temp_list.append(ln)
        # don't need to close because at the end of the "with" statement
        #the file is automaticly close
address_list[i] = [] # replace the old value by a list so you can 
                     #append
for j in temp_list:
    address_list[i].append(j)
```

(not tested) code 2:

```
for i, _ in enumerate(address_list):
    temp_list = []
    with open(file_path_simple, 'r') as fp:
        for ln in fp:
            ln = ln.strip('\n')
            temp_list.append(ln)
    address_list[i] = temp_list
```

don't mind my poor english,
Flayme